# get full image path and put in img src using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the fullpath of image that i select in , and the problem after i select the image there is no image appear.

help me please :)

Here is my code.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function imgchange()
{
        var filePath = $('#file').val();
        $("#imgs").attr('src',filePath);
}
</script>
```

HTML

```
            <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <center>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><center><img id="imgs" width="170px" height="160px" ></img></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><b><label for="file">Filename:</label></b></td><td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="imgchange()"></td>
                        </tr>                               
                    </table>    
                </center>
            <div class="buttons_save">
                <button class="buttons_profile3" id="btnSubmit" >SAVE</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: try this http://jsbin.com/uboqu3/1/edit

Comment: you need to use a blob to do this

Comment: There is inbuilt jquery plugin if you are interested. link : http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Answer (score 12):

DEMO: - **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/KTyA4/1/)**

Try this:

Here is the HTML code:-

```
<input type="file" id="i_file" value=""> 
<input type="button" id="i_submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
<img src="" width="200" style="display:none;" />
```

Here is the JS:-

```
$('#i_file').change( function(event) {
    $("img").fadeIn("fast").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
});
```

Comment: Which api do i need to use URL.createObjectURL() function ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/wTd58/

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <center>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
               <center><img id="imgs" width="170px" height="160px" ></img></center>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td align="right"><b><label for="file">Filename:</label></b></td>
            <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="imgchange(this)"></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </center>
   <div class="buttons_save">
      <button class="buttons_profile3" id="btnSubmit" >SAVE</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
       function imgchange(f) {
           var filePath = $('#file').val();
           var reader = new FileReader();
           reader.onload = function (e) {
               $('#imgs').attr('src',e.target.result);
           };
           reader.readAsDataURL(f.files[0]);           
        }
```

Comment: I dont think you really need to use a reader when the file input already stores the image in a url accessible by the client.

Answer (score 1):

All browsers may not give you the exact path. You can use blob location like this:

`function imgchange(event){
    $("#imgs").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
}`

In your input you can use `onchange="imgchange(event)"`

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A389D/)

Comment: From mozilla website, it says this is not yet stebilized and subject to change. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this unless you have uploaded the file to a server you can't show it in the browser, because the file goes to a virtualpath "C:/fakepath/" and you can't point any image to it. First you have to upload the image to server then provide the server path to the image.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
 <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <center>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><center><img id="imgs" width="170px" height="160px" ></img></center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right"><b><label for="file">Filename:</label></b></td><td><input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="imgchange(event)"></td>
                        </tr>                               
                    </table>    
                </center>
            <div class="buttons_save">
                <button class="buttons_profile3" id="btnSubmit" >SAVE</button>
            </div>
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function imgchange(e)
   {
        $("#imgs").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple code to display image on browser

```
function imgchange(event){
    $("#imgs").attr('src',URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(260)
                .height(100);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```